# Elegant way to determine EOF?

Tags: c, file, eof

I am reading from a text file, iterating with a `while(!feof)` loop,
but whenever I use this condition the loop iterates an extra time.

I solved the problem with this 'patchy' code

```
while (stop == FALSE)
{
 ...

        terminator = fgetc(input);
        if (terminator == EOF)
            stop = TRUE;
        else
            fseek(input, -1, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

But it looks and feels very bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: probably 20th question about C IO in the last few days, probably we need a community wiki page for that

Comment: @H2CO3: Technically not a duplicate for the iostream question, since this is specifically C and the other is C++.

Comment: @jev: There's always a rash of questions like this in late summer/early autumn, when the programming courses get started.  A community wiki page might be a good idea.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy yes; the concept is identical, though.

Comment: The way you've written it is not the most common idiom (see the answers for that), but aside from that `while (stop == FALSE)` is better written as `while (!stop)`. (If you think `(stop == FALSE)` is better because it's more explicit, how do you feel about `((stop == FALSE) == TRUE)`?). The identifiers `TRUE` and `FALSE` are non-standard anyway.

Comment: @KeithThompson so does `BOOL` in C, but it's a simple typedef and two definitions which makes life alot easier...

Comment: @Quaker: C has has `bool`, `false`, and `true` (defined in `<stdbool.h>` since 1999 -- unless you're stuck using Microsoft's compiler. My point is that, even with `true` and `false` (or `TRUE` and `FALSE`), `while (!stop)` is clearer. And comparing a value for equality to `TRUE`/`true` can actually fail, since any non-zero value is true, but only `1` is *equal* to `true`. If you already have a boolean value, just use it as a boolean value.

Comment: @KeithThompson You were actually correct with the Micro$oft compiler. The thing about `!stop` and the use of boolean value is something I never though of or read of and it's quite important for every programmer to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that an assignment gets evaluated as the value being assigned, in this case to the character being read:

```
while((terminator = fgetc(input))!= EOF) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it keep the cursor a char ahead in case `!= EOF`?

Comment: @Quaker No, why would it?

Comment: Since fgetc advances the indicator one char at a time and if `terminator != EOF` then `terminator` will hold a relevant char and the indicator will be ahead of it.

Comment: @Quaker What kind of "cursor"? And why do you care at all? you will have your freshly read character in `terminator`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an idiomatic example ([source](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/getc.html)):

```
fp = fopen("datafile.txt", "r"); // error check this!

// this while-statement assigns into c, and then checks against EOF:

while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    /* ... */
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. The fantastic enthusiasm around `feof()` in questions here is ... tiring.

Comment: @unwind Isn't the other answer equally correct as well, by the way?

Comment: Brian, I am reading the text file line by line with a function that reads the entire line to a string. Wouldn't your solution result in a trimmed string (missing the first char of the line)?

Comment: @Quaker Again, no. Why would it?

Comment: @H2CO3, `The internal file position indicator is then advanced to the next character.` Taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/

Comment: @Quaker Well, then you need to think about that more. It isn't broken.

Comment: @Quaker, a little nitpick -- please don't cite C++ references in a question tagged 'C'.

Comment: Thinking about it more gets me back to where I began with `        if (terminator == EOF)
            stop = TRUE;` If this is the elegant way to solve it than the answer should have been `There is no better way`...

Comment: @Quaker Well, the solution presented in these answers is definitely a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly you ca read line-by-line:

```
char buf[MAXLINE];
// ...
while((fgets(buf,MAXLINE,stdin)) != NULL) {
       do_something(buf);
}
```

Since `fgets` copies the detected newline character, you can detect 
end of line by checking the second to last buffer element. You can use
`realloc` to resize the buffer (be sure you keep a pointer to the beginning of the buffer, but pass `buf+n`, to the next fgets, where `n` is the number of read characters). From the standard regarding `fgets`:

> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first. A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.

Alternatively, you could read the whole file in one go using [fread()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) (see example following the link).